# Excel: file opens with USA date format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm experiencing something a little weird.

I created a file while I was in America. This file automatically opens various other files and imports them. These imported files contain dates.

I am now back in the UK and when I open these files automatically through the code, the dates get flipped around. However, when I open these same files manually, the dates are correct.

Anyone have any idea how I can stop this from happening when I automatically open the files? Maybe some default setting in the master file because it was created in America?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Try changing the `Local` property when using `Workbooks.Open` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx)).

Comment: What do you mean when you open them automatically? Via a macro?  Are you still using the same computer as when you created it, or did you create the file in the US, on a "US" computer (i.e. a computer in the office there). It may be the computer's regional settings.

Comment: @Jordan, what is the syntax for that? I'm trying "Workbooks.Open (data_Location & "Lease.csv", Local = TRUE)" but this isn't working

Comment: @BruceWayne, yes, via a macro. I created the file on a US machine, but am now back on my UK PC. When I open the file manually, it opens with the correct date, but when I open through the US created file, it opens with the US date (and if, for example, the date is 25Jun16, it gets confused and puts it as 06/25/2016, and doesn't recognise this as a date)

Comment: Changed it to this: "Workbooks.Open Filename:=data_Location & "Lease.csv", Local:=True" and it works. Thank you! Been having a nightmare with that all day!

Comment: I think it's `Local:=TRUE`

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you pop in an answer, I can mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701215/excel-file-opens-with-usa-date-format#comment72525095_42701215) by OP:

> Changed it to this:
>
> ```
> Workbooks.Open Filename:=data_Location & "Lease.csv", Local:=True
> ```
>
> and it works.